# C++: Using base class's private members in equality test

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I would like the following to compile, but it does not:

```
template <typename T>
struct Odp
{
public:
    operator*() const
    {
        return m_p;
    }

    T* operator->() const
    {
        return m_p;
    }

    T** operator&()
    {
        return &m_p;
    }

private:
        T* m_p;

};

struct Ftw : public Odp<int>
{
    bool operator==(const Ftw& rhs)
    {
        return m_p == rhs.m_p; // C2248 cannot access private member
    } 
};
```

Is there any way to make this work? I can't modify `Odp`.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the code. Type returned by operator*() is not specified and the return statement is the same as in operator->().

Comment: I'm beginning to get a bit bored with Odp. You seem to be asking the same question in slightly different ways. And the basic answer seems to be - don't create the derived class.

Comment: @Neil you are correct that 1) I use `Odp` as my random name of choice and 2) I am asking similar questions. The problem is that I can't change this base class, but I need to defined the `==` operator on it so it can be used in an STL set. (Or maybe I'm mistaken in that belief?)

Comment: In your first question, Neil (and I :) ) gave perfectly reasonable answers: define a free operator overload, or use a function object. By the way `std::set` requires an ordering predicate (less-than), not an equality test. - It seems you have been posting wrong questions (how to code what I think is a solution, not what is the solution), although the code for the freestanding predicate won't be any different from the code for the derived class (inheritance doesn't buy you anything).

Comment: @Rosarch As UncleBen says, you need to define a less-than operator, and you can do that as a free function, as I described in my answer to your other question.

Comment: How do I provide this freestanding operator to the `set`? Can you post a code example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Odp` overloads `operator*` to return `m_p`.  You can invoke the operator on `*this` and `rhs`:

```
struct Ftw : public Odp<int>
{
    bool operator==(const Ftw& rhs) const
    {
        return **this == *rhs;
    } 
};
```

The `operator*` overload is a bit unusual, however:  it should probably return `*m_p` instead, since `operator->` returns `m_p` (this would result in your class having consistent pointer-like semantics).  If you did this, you would then have to do the following to do the comparison:

```
return &**this == &*rhs; // or explicitly as:
return &this->operator*() == &rhs.operator*();
```

This is getting a bit messy, and it won't necessarily work if the unary `&` is overloaded for `T` (but, you really, *really* shouldn't do that...).  You can also obtain the pointer by explicitly calling `operator->`, which might be preferable:

```
return this->operator->() == rhs.operator->();
```

The real question is, "what is this `Odp`, why are you using it, and why can you not modify it?"

---

On an unrelated note, your `operator==` should either be implemented as a const member function or, preferably, as a friend function:

```
bool operator==(const Ftw& rhs) const { /* ... */ }
friend bool operator==(const Ftw& lhs, const Ftw& rhs) { /* ... */ }
```

On another unrelated note, overloading the unary `&` is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: I think I would call `operator*` explicitly here.  `return this->operator*() == rhs.operator*();`

Comment: @Ben:  Out of curiosity, is there a particular reason you prefer the explicit `operator` syntax in this case?  I generally avoid calling operators explicitly wherever possible because it seems to defeat the purpose of operator overloading (of course, given the requirements of this question, that is somewhat reasonable).  I think the only time I've called an operator explicitly in production code is when I made an interesting design decision (read:  royally screwed up) and made a `operator[]` template, only to realize later that it could only be called explicitly :-O.

Comment: I guess because the intent of the code isn't *use the object through the smart pointer*, it's *retrieve the pointer address from the smart pointer*.  Maybe that reasoning is only applicable to `operator->` though.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you that m_p is private. If you want to access m_p in the derived class you need to make it either protected or public.

Comment: ... or rather use the existing public interface, which seems to provide altogether 3 different ways to get to `m_p`!

Comment: My answer follows what I thought was the author's intent. He specifically asked how to get what he wrote to work. To implement the operator as he has written, he will have to make the member protected or public.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify `Odp`, you can call `operator->()` explicitly. It returns what you need and should get inlined.

Comment: @Rosarch Thx for the edit, but You missed two other cases of "You" in this sentence. If capitalizing the first letter in "You" (which I do consistently for some reason, but maybe it's inappropriate for reasons I don't know of) is annoying please tell me. I'll stop.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps I should been more consistent. I saw the one, figured it was a typo (because capitalizing You typically means you're referring to a deity), then fixed it. Then I saw you were being consistent in your usage, and for some reason decided not to fix the rest. I guess if I'm going to go correcting others I might as well be a bit more conscientious about it.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Odp` is giving the pointer out for free in its methods (even the address of it, OMG! it's like making door with many locks and then giving the keys to every thief around), you can just do

```
bool operator==(const Ftw& rhs)
{
    return **this == *rhs;
}
```

Had `Odp` implemented its own comparison operator, you could use it like this:

```
bool operator==(const Ftw& rhs)
{
    return Odp<int>::operator==(rhs) && ... other conditions ...;
}
```